# What happens to a shared memory area when a process dies?

Tags: linux, process, memory

I'm wondering what happens with shared memory created with `shmget()` as shown on http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/example-2.html when any of the processes terminate or die? Is the area freed or will it persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will persist, it must explicitly be deleted with `shmctl IPC_RMID`

> Mark the segment to be destroyed. The segment will actually be destroyed only after the last process detaches it ... The caller must be the owner or creator of the segment, or be privileged.

Comment: Does `The segment will actually be destroyed only after the last process detaches it` mean that it will be removed after all "users" have died?

Comment: Yes, similar to how an unlinked file will only be removed after the last process closes it.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the author of the application know how to deal with that problem.

Many applications are written so that they call

```
shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, 0);
```

after they stopped using the shared memory segment.

In this case, the memory segment will continue to exist after the program dies unexpectedly e.g. with a coredump.

If the program however calls `shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, 0);` directly after it attached the memory segment, the kernel will do the needed housekeeping for any kind of program termination.

Comment: In case you want to cleanup the "dangling" shared memory, you can use `ipcrm -a`. Warning from Linux man page: 

Warning!  Do not use -a if you are unsure how the software using the resources might react to missing objects. Some programs create these resources at startup and may not have any code to deal with an unexpected disappearance.

Comment: @lol `ipcrm` does not have such an option. This is a non-portable Linux feature. If it really destroys objects with removed id, this would be an unfriendly act for programs that,but I guess that this just does an `IPC_RMID`.